# Manage photo in sharepoint 2010

Tags: custom-list, visual-web-part, image-upload

I have a list for students. I want to keep photos of each student. How can i do this? Do I need to add a field to Student custom list? Please help me with correct approach. I am using a visual webpart to add items to the Students list. How can i upload photo using same visual webpart?

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to create a Column in you **Student List** and Set its type to **Picture or HyperLink** and select Picture from Dropdown.

2) Create a Picture Library named like **Student Photos**.

3) While Saving Student Data Upload Student Photo with it and Save that photo to **Student Photos** Picture Library.

4) Save link of that Photo to your **Student List**